# puppeteer page.evaluate() randomly fails with: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, serverless

The following code randomly fails with:

> Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of navigation.

Why is that?
Any workarounds?

I use puppeteer version 1.19.0

**Note:** I'm looking for a general solution that allows navigating to both pages that have redirects, and pages that don't.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  try {
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setCacheEnabled(false);

    const response = await page.goto("https://docs.cypress.io/", {
      waitUntil: "networkidle0",
      timeout: 60000
    });

    const pageUrls = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a"));

      return links.map(link => link.href);
    });

    console.log({ pageUrls });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a Workarounds - Add below code

`await page.waitForNavigation()`

after calling  page.goto() Or if same issue occurs for page.click() you can wait for navigation using above method.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  try {
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setCacheEnabled(false);

    const response = await page.goto("https://docs.cypress.io/", {
      waitUntil: "networkidle0",
      timeout: 60000
    });

    await page.waitForNavigation();

    const pageUrls = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a"));

      return links.map(link => link.href);
    });

    console.log({ pageUrls });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

**Output :**

```
{ pageUrls:
   [ 'https://twitter.com/amirrustam',
     'https://www.componentsconf.com.au/workshops',
     'https://www.cypress.io/',
     'https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress.html',
     'https://docs.cypress.io/api/api/table-of-contents.html',
     'https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/',
     'https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes.html',
     'https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html',.................]
```

**Edit**

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    try {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setCacheEnabled(false);

        await Promise.all([
            page.waitForNavigation({ timeout: 60000 }),
            page.goto("https://www.google.com/", {
                waitUntil: "networkidle0",
                timeout: 60000
            })
        ])

        const pageUrls = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a"));
            return links.map(link => link.href);
        });
        console.log({ pageUrls });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Output:

```
{ pageUrls:
   [ 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm&ogbl',
     'https://www.google.co.in/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi&ogbl',
     'https://www.google.co.in/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh',
     'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.com/',
     'https://www.google.com/#',............
```

Comment: The problem with `await page.waitForNavigation()` is that you need to know in advance that there is a redirect to another page. If you try a different URL that doesn't redirect (e.g. https://google.com), `waitForNavigation` eventually times out. I'm looking for a general solution that follows redirects if they exist, but doesn't time out on pages that don't have redirects.

Comment: You can refer to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions  You can increase the timeout   . You can try in case of clicks . `await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(), // The promise resolves after navigation has finished
  page.click('a.my-link'), // Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
]);`

Comment: If you are observing time out in waitfornavigation then it may be because of race condition https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3338#issuecomment-426584706

Comment: @RahulL , I used the same code, but there was an error， TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined.